@JsonCodable() throwing error in Dart 3.4
I have added JsonCodable to Latest flutter verion 3.22.0 for JsonData class. But some how Dart analysis server is throwing error. I have also added macros to pubspec.yaml and made enable-experiment to this file.
Pubspec.yaml

Analysis Options.yaml

my_code.dart


I am on Flutter 3.22.0, doc says I need to be on Flutter master channel.
https://dart.dev/language/macros#the-jsoncodable-macro

For that annotation you need to add json: ^0.20.1 package in your pubspec.yaml
See

Macros: The JsonCodable macro
Pub.dev: json package


To utilize the new macros features in Dart and the json package, you'll need upgrade your dart sdk to version 3.5.0 which can be done via switching to the Flutter master channel with flutter channel master. This updates your Dart version and enables access to these experimental features.

Remember, the master channel provides the absolute latest features, but it may contain unstable builds. While typically functional, there's a chance of encountering unforeseen issues.

Also don't forget add the json package in your pubspec.yaml file :
...
dependencies:
  json: ^0.20.1

Macros documentation : https://dart.dev/language/macros#the-jsoncodable-macro
